# What type of keyboard is Caden Cotard using?

Tags: props, synecdoche-new-york

Movie Title: **Synecdoche, New York (2008)**

Did director charlie Kaufman create this keyboard for the movie or does it really exist? It looks so different.

[image]

Comment: Most likely some kind of an ergonomic keyboard

Comment: I don't know about that specific one but that style definitely exists, e.g. the [Microsoft Natural keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Natural_keyboard) range

Comment: There are many, many keyboards like this. Could you specify what you think is unusual about it?

Comment: @Walt most people arnt used to seeing ergonomic split key keyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a regular Microsoft Natural Keyboard Elite. It's a split key format, for ergonomic purposes (read: prevents carpal tunnel or repetitive stress injuries of the wrist). It's considered one of the best split key keyboards, with nice heavy clicky action (for a membrane based keyboard). It (the whole series really) is consistently ranked as one of the best keyboards.

***It's an off the shelf product, not a specially designed prop.***

Source: looking at the one ten feet to my left.